# Maintaining configured variables between "Execute Shell" sections in Jenkins

Tags: bash, jenkins, environment-variables

I have a few build scripts I'm working on in my Jenkins CI server.  In order to keep things organized, I tend to keep each "Execute Shell" section of the job smaller and isolated in scope.

Let's say I'm building up a string value I want to use later in various places in my job.  (e.g. name of the tag, message associated with the tag, date formatting, etc...)

```
Execute Shell #1
# Utilizing Multiple Lines and temporary variables for readability
tagName="$tagName_Sub1 $tagName_Sub2 $tagName_Sub3"

Execute Shell #2
# Build Script - tagName is an argument to my build script
run build_job $tagName

Execute Shell #3
# Tag Git
git tag -a $tagName

Execute Shell #4
# Something else
echo "Hello World, $tagName"
```

Comment: It looks like what you actually want is an array, not a string. Consider *defining* an array: `tagNames=( "$tagName_Sub1" "$tagName_Sub2" "$tagName_Sub3" )`, then using it appropriately, with `"${tagNames[@]}"`.

Comment: Otherwise, you'll have a very unpleasant time of it when you're trying to use a tag name with a literal space in it, with non-space characters that have been temporarily added to IFS, or that can be interpreted as a glob that matches filesystem content.

Comment: ...see http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050 -- the caveats and advice in there apply to any case where `$foo` (without surrounding double quotes) is used as part of command line generation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't exist a general answer: One can export variables only to direct subprocesses without direct cooperation of a parent process; however, having a build directory provides you a shared store which can be used cooperatively your siblings.

---

You can thus use `declare -p` to generate a script component which, when sourced, will recreate a variable as it existed in the prior shell instance:

```
declare -p tagName >vars # optionally, you can put more than one variable name here
```

...then, in other code:

```
source vars # import all variables written to the file
```

Using `declare -p` serializes status in terms of not just contents (appropriately quoted or escaped to be safely read back), but also whether a variable has been exported; whether it is an array or a regular string; whether it's flagged for special treatment as an integer; and otherwise ensures that what you get out is genuinely what you saved.

Do be sure that all the scripts involved are actually run with `/bin/bash`, not `/bin/sh`; this is bash-specific syntax.

Comment: Thanks, this worked great.  I declared everything into "vars" and I added "source vars" to the top of all my Execute Shell blocks and everything worked.